# Why is the exterior algebra called the "exterior algebra?" What makes it "exterior?"

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, terminology, math-history

Why is the exterior algebra called the "exterior algebra?" What makes it "exterior?" Is it just because a module can be universally embedded into its exterior algebra, so one could view the exterior algebra as surrounding the module? Why is it not just called the "alternating algebra?"

Comment: Probably hard to track down, especially since the reason might be a foreign-language thing. Grassmann referred to *aussere produkt* and you can read about *äußeren Algebra* in German wikipedia. I don't speak German, but it seems like from the start "external/outer/exterior" was used.  English wikipedia offers this (speculative, IMO) reason: *The term "exterior" comes from the exterior product of two vectors not being a vector.* In any case, this is not a math question, it is one for [historians](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @rschwieb well, we do have the math-history tag (which explicitly targets evolution of terminology).

Comment: @Thomas Over time, we phase out those tags in favor of the devoted stackexchanges, though...

Comment: @rschwieb fine with me. This one is still there, though. Edit: and, actually, who is the 'we' you are referring to? This site is run by its participants. So as far as I'm concerned, I'm part of 'we', As is the OP. So whether 'we' will phase out or not -- we'll see....

Comment: Dear @Thomas That's right, you got it. "We" the participants. I think(?) you understand that the collective group of participants can't always share our same personal opinions, so I'm not sure why you are emphasizing our individuality so much. I'm simply stating a historical pattern that is likely to occur. An example of such an occuence is that the [advice] tag is no longer so useful, and sometimes we direct a subset of those questions to academia.se. Regards.

Comment: Dear @Thomas : Perhaps more to the point, maybe I should just say that the mere existence of a tag does not justify questions using the tag for all eternity, which is why I mentioned we sometimes phase out tags. Regards

Comment: It would be nice if the exterior algebra bore some relation to interior algebras.  I guess mathematics outgrew the English language a long time ago.

Comment: @Thomas the phasing out does not necessarily result in removal of the tag. What's more the tag description does in fact already recommend the other site.  Moreover, there are also *mathematical* questions  that have a historically aspect to them for which the tag is useful to keep  around. Note that the site also has a physics tag, while physics proper is certainly not on-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does exterior algebra actually mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729411/what-does-exterior-algebra-actually-mean)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It was Grassmann that called it exterior because to have a non-null product the multiplicands must be geometrically one to the *exterior* of the other. For instance $$\mathbf{x}\wedge\mathbf{y}\wedge\mathbf{z}=0$$
if $\mathbf{x}$ lies in (is not exterior of) the subspace spanned by the $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{z}$. So the product is called exterior product, and consequently the algebra with this product is called exterior algebra.

Comment: @levap Thanks for your comments. I edited accordingly